Data with duplicate headers to a single table without duplicate headers
I have source data (that is loaded from an outside source) that has 193 columns. (The number of rows is dynamic.) Most of these columns have a duplicate column header. I need to compress the data to create a table where the duplicate headers are merged into single columns.
